# Can't add listener to a SVG in Internet Explorer using SVGweb

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events

This code works great in Firefox, but not in IE. I've read the documentation of SVGWeb (http://svgweb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/UserManual.html), but I don't find/understand the solution, any idea?

```
window.onsvgload = function() {
  carga();
var mySVG = document.getElementById("mySVGObject").contentDocument;
        mySVG.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
                alert(evt.target.id);
    }, false);
}
```

I'm using things like this in IE without problems:

```
mySVG.getElementById('Color2').style.fill='#00cc00'
```

with that code I can change colors and texts in the shape, but I cannot make the listener work in IE.

Edit: this works in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, I need it to work on IE7.
This is how I load the SVG object:

```
 <div style="text-align:center" id="mapaSvg" >
<!--[if !IE]>-->
 <object data="ca.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
      width="700" height="800" id="mySVGObject" > <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<object src="ca.svg" classid="image/svg+xml"
      width="700" height="800" id="mySVGObject" > <![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<object data="ca.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
      width="700" height="800" id="mySVGObject" > <![endif]-->
</object>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
```

The IE development tools show the error:

> "Error while firing onload: Not supported"

On the line:

```
mySVG.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
                alert(evt.target.id);
    }, false);
```

Here you can see an example of SVGWEB working in IE, Firefox, Chrome on mouse over of dynamic lines:
https://www.destatis.de/bevoelkerungspyramide/

Comment: You could add a transparent div overlay and dispatch the mouse events in your code.

Comment: I understand what you say, but in the documentation it said that SVGWEB can add listeners that can be used in IE. These are maps and there are many and have different shapes/regions/etc, the div overlay isn't a solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with something like this:

Comment: if (element.addEventListener)
                element.addEventListener('click', funcHandle, false);
            else if (element.attachEvent)
                element.attachEvent('onclick', funcHandle);

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, just tried that, nothing changed, when I go to developer console I get this when I try each method
**>>mySVG.attachEvent**
_undefined_

**>>mySVG.addEventListener**
_{...}_

Im starting to think that it has something to do with function(evt), when I remove that nothing happens obviously but I don't get the **Error while firing onload: Not supported** when the script go trough that line.
Thanks!

Comment: does this change something:

Comment: function myFunc() {
 alert("myfunc");
}
mySVG.addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);

Comment: @Matthias Same error **Error while firing onload: Not supported**
If i sent line by line in the development tools in debugger I get:
mySVG.addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);
**Exception thrown and not caught**
with mySVG.addEventListener('click', alert('a'), false);
It obviously show the alert on load, no error, but...it doesnt work obviously
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `addEventListener` inside this block instead `onsvgload`:

```
window.addEventListener('SVGLoad', function() {
   // all SVG loaded and rendered
}, false)
```

These constructions are equal but I make this assumption because of an error: "Error while firing onload: Not supported"

Comment: It was a good idea, thanks! but i have the same error in same line.

Comment: hm... it's interesting. Maybe you are using `jQuery`? It looks like there is a compatibility issue: https://bitbucket.org/thomaswaldmann/moin-2.0/issue/265/svgweb-fails-on-ie7-and-ie8

Comment: Not, only this: SVGWEB and AMCHARTS (tried disabled amcharts without results) thanks

Comment: Then, most likely due to the fact that IE7 does not support SVG it's just cann't fire event related to render SVG. But it's only my opinion =) I am sorry that I was not able to help you

Comment: Thakyou, but I see that addeventlistener works great for SVGs created "on the fly", for example: https://www.destatis.de/bevoelkerungspyramide/
There has to be a way to make it work. If not I will try Raphael, but I have all fitted to SVGWEB
Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! If you will find the answer - please post it in comments ;)
It seems like many people interested in it.

Comment: @user1652904 I think this is true. And if you look into the documentation you will find this:

Comment: "By default, the Flash renderer will be used on Internet Explorer 6 through 8", So you probably need to inspect the element to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps but I had much the same problem with it working in every browser except IE8 and IE7. The problem was caused by using a self closing image element `<image/>` instead of `<image></image>` in the svg.

Comment: Thanks @Hoppy, but that isnt the case this time.