# Weird results when converting SVG to js for Raphael

Tags: svg, raphael, svgweb

Im trying to use this image with Raphael:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Argentina_Buenos_Aires_City_location_map.svg

I convert it to js with: http://toki-woki.net/p/SVG2RaphaelJS/

And I get this:
[image: converted image]

Any Idea of what can I do to solve this? This is worst apparently when I add text in inkscape above each reagion to change later via javascript.

Im using SVGWEB now without problems buy Im trying another alternatives because I cannot make the addeventlistener work in IE7/8 like I said here:
[can't add listener to a SVG in Internet Explorer using SVGweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119456/cant-add-listener-to-a-svg-in-internet-explorer-using-svgweb)
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try mapSVG plugin instead.

Demo with your map: http://map.karaliki.ru/bu.html (zoom in-out with mouse wheel)
It works in IE7-8 as well.

Plugin's description: http://map.karaliki.ru

Comment: Great solution but its too slow in IE, like full processor usage to load the map for a minute or so. It works great in FF (like svgweb).